# PyQt5 Linux Mint Cinnamon native 'delete', 'apply' buttons

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5, linux-mint, cinnamon

I'm trying to create a pyqt5 application on Linux mint 19 (cinnamon).
I have a 'delete' and 'apply' buttons, but i want to give them more relevant look. Like on this pictures:

native Linux mint buttons

[image]

more

[image]

It is a native look of buttons with apply or delete role on linux mint and I want to create buttons like this in my application, but I haven't found a way to do so.

It seems that windows and mac have `qtmacextras` and `qtwinextras` modules for such stuff. Linux have some kind of `qtx11extras`, but that module does not provide such functionality.

Comment: Those buttons look like they're based on Gtk themeing, so I sincerely doubt that you can make your program look the same based on it. Check `QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.keys()` and test the available styles on your app using `app.setStyle(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.create("name"))` (assuming you created `app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)`). Otherwise, the only options are to use stylesheets or subclassing QProxyStyle().

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes those buttons are based on Gtk themeing. I'll try your way, it looks pretty interesting.

Comment: The possible answer was to use Gtk+ graphic library for python, which provides all native widgets.

Too bad that I already wrote all my program code using PyQt5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the solution already provided works perfectly, is not completely application wide, especially if you want to control the appearance of buttons of dialogs.

Even if you apply the stylesheet to the application, you'll need to ensure to correctly set the selectors in parents: in the other answer, for example, setting the background property without selectors will clear the app stylesheet inheritance of the children.

Assuming the stylesheet is set to the application and all other stylesheets set are carefully written, the problem comes with dialog windows.

If the dialog is created manually, alternate colors can be set by specifying the stylesheet for each button for which you want the alternate color, but this is impossible for those created with static functions.

In that case, the only possibility is to use a QProxyStyle. The following is a possible implementation that also allows to set custom colors and fonts, and automatically sets an alternate color for "negative" roles of dialog button boxes (cancel, ignore, etc).

In this example I just applied the style to the application, but the message box is created using the `information()` static function. The "Alternate" button is manually set using a custom property: `button.setProperty('alternateColor', True)`.

[image: Cool colored buttons!]

```
class ColorButtonStyle(QtWidgets.QProxyStyle):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if isinstance(kwargs.get('buttonFont'), QtGui.QFont):
            self._buttonFont = kwargs.pop('buttonFont')
        else:
            self._buttonFont = QtWidgets.QApplication.font()
            self._buttonFont.setPointSize(20)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._buttonFontMetrics = QtGui.QFontMetrics(self._buttonFont)
        self._defaultButtonColor = QtGui.QColor(109, 180, 66)
        self._defaultTextColor = QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.white)
        self._alternateButtonColor = QtGui.QColor(240, 74, 80)
        self._alternateTextColor = None
        self._alternateRoles = set((
            QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.RejectRole, 
            QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.DestructiveRole, 
            QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.NoRole, 
        ))

    def _polishApp(self):
        self.polish(QtWidgets.QApplication.instance())

    def buttonFont(self):
        return QtGui.QFont(self._buttonFont)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtGui.QFont)
    def setButtonFont(self, font):
        if not isinstance(font, QtGui.QFont) or font == self._buttonFont:
            return
        self._buttonFont = font
        self._buttonFontMetrics = QtGui.QFontMetrics(self._buttonFont)
        self._polishApp()

    def defaultButtonColor(self):
        return QtGui.QColor(self._defaultButtonColor)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.Qt.GlobalColor)
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtGui.QColor)
    def setDefaultButtonColor(self, color):
        if isinstance(color, QtCore.Qt.GlobalColor):
            color = QtGui.QColor(color)
        elif not isinstance(color, QtGui.QColor):
            return
        self._defaultButtonColor = color
        self._polishApp()

    def alternateButtonColor(self):
        return QtGui.QColor(self._alternateButtonColor)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.Qt.GlobalColor)
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtGui.QColor)
    def setAlternateButtonColor(self, color):
        if isinstance(color, QtCore.Qt.GlobalColor):
            color = QtGui.QColor(color)
        elif not isinstance(color, QtGui.QColor):
            return
        self._alternateButtonColor = color
        self._polishApp()

    def alternateRoles(self):
        return self._alternateRoles

    def setAlternateRoles(self, roles):
        newRoles = set()
        for role in roles:
            if isinstance(role, QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.ButtonRole):
                newRoles.add(role)
        if newRoles != self._alternateRoles:
            self._alternateRoles = newRoles
            self._polishApp()

    def setAlternateRole(self, role, activate=True):
        if isinstance(role, QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.ButtonRole):
            if activate and role in self._alternateRoles:
                self._alternateRoles.add(role)
                self._polishApp()
            elif not activate and role not in self._alternateRoles:
                self._alternateRoles.remove(role)
                self._polishApp()

    def defaultTextColor(self):
        return QtGui.QColor(self._defaultTextColor)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.Qt.GlobalColor)
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtGui.QColor)
    def setDefaultTextColor(self, color):
        if isinstance(color, QtCore.Qt.GlobalColor):
            color = QtGui.QColor(color)
        elif not isinstance(color, QtGui.QColor):
            return
        self._defaultTextColor = color
        self._polishApp()

    def alternateTextColor(self):
        return QtGui.QColor(self._alternateTextColor or self._defaultTextColor)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.Qt.GlobalColor)
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtGui.QColor)
    def setAlternateTextColor(self, color):
        if isinstance(color, QtCore.Qt.GlobalColor):
            color = QtGui.QColor(color)
        elif not isinstance(color, QtGui.QColor):
            return
        self._alternateTextColor = color
        self._polishApp()

    def drawControl(self, element, option, painter, widget):
        if element == self.CE_PushButton:
            isAlternate = False
            if widget and isinstance(widget.parent(), QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox):
                role = widget.parent().buttonRole(widget)
                if role in self._alternateRoles:
                    isAlternate = True
            elif widget.property('alternateColor'):
                isAlternate = True

            if isAlternate:
                color = self.alternateButtonColor()
                textColor = self.alternateTextColor()
            else:
                color = self.defaultButtonColor()
                textColor = self.defaultTextColor()

            if not option.state & self.State_Enabled:
                color.setAlpha(color.alpha() * .75)
                textColor.setAlpha(textColor.alpha() * .75)

            # switch the existing palette with a new one created from it;
            # this shouldn't be necessary, but better safe than sorry
            oldPalette = option.palette
            palette = QtGui.QPalette(oldPalette)
            palette.setColor(palette.ButtonText, textColor)
            # some styles use WindowText for flat buttons
            palette.setColor(palette.WindowText, textColor)
            option.palette = palette

            # colors that are almost black are not very affected by "lighter"
            if color.value() < 32:
                lightColor = QtGui.QColor(48, 48, 48, color.alpha())
            else:
                lightColor = color.lighter(115)
            darkColor = color.darker()
            if option.state & self.State_MouseOver:
                # colors that are almost black are not very affected by "lighter"
                bgColor = lightColor
                lighterColor = lightColor.lighter(115)
                darkerColor = darkColor.darker(115)
            else:
                bgColor = color
                lighterColor = lightColor
                darkerColor = darkColor
            if option.state & self.State_Raised and not option.state & self.State_On:
                topLeftPen = QtGui.QPen(lighterColor)
                bottomRightPen = QtGui.QPen(darkerColor)
            elif option.state & (self.State_On | self.State_Sunken):
                if option.state & self.State_On:
                    bgColor = bgColor.darker()
                else:
                    bgColor = bgColor.darker(125)
                topLeftPen = QtGui.QPen(darkColor)
                bottomRightPen = QtGui.QPen(lighterColor)
            else:
                topLeftPen = bottomRightPen = QtGui.QPen(bgColor)

            painter.save()
            painter.setRenderHints(painter.Antialiasing)
            painter.translate(.5, .5)
            rect = option.rect.adjusted(0, 0, -1, -1)
            painter.setBrush(bgColor)
            painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen)
            painter.drawRoundedRect(rect, 2, 2)

            if topLeftPen != bottomRightPen:
                roundRect = QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 4, 4)
                painter.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.NoBrush)

                # the top and left borders
                tlPath = QtGui.QPainterPath()
                tlPath.arcMoveTo(roundRect.translated(0, rect.height() - 4), 225)
                tlPath.arcTo(roundRect.translated(0, rect.height() - 4), 225, -45)
                tlPath.arcTo(roundRect, 180, -90)
                tlPath.arcTo(roundRect.translated(rect.width() - 4, 0), 90, -45)
                painter.setPen(topLeftPen)
                painter.drawPath(tlPath)

                # the bottom and right borders
                brPath = QtGui.QPainterPath(tlPath.currentPosition())
                brPath.arcTo(roundRect.translated(rect.width() - 4, 0), 45, -45)
                brPath.arcTo(
                    roundRect.translated(rect.width() - 4, rect.height() - 4), 0, -90)
                brPath.arcTo(
                    roundRect.translated(0, rect.height() - 4), 270, -45)
                painter.setPen(bottomRightPen)
                painter.drawPath(brPath)


            if option.state & self.State_HasFocus:
                focusColor = QtGui.QColor(textColor).darker()
                focusColor.setAlpha(focusColor.alpha() * .75)
                painter.setPen(focusColor)
                painter.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.NoBrush)
                painter.drawRoundedRect(rect.adjusted(2, 2, -2, -2), 2, 2)

            painter.setFont(self._buttonFont)
            oldMetrics = option.fontMetrics
            option.fontMetrics = self._buttonFontMetrics
            self.drawControl(self.CE_PushButtonLabel, option, painter, widget)
            painter.restore()

            # restore the original font metrics and palette
            option.fontMetrics = oldMetrics
            option.palette = oldPalette
            return

        super().drawControl(element, option, painter, widget)

    def sizeFromContents(self, contentsType, option, size, widget=None):
        if contentsType == self.CT_PushButton:
            if option.text:
                textSize = option.fontMetrics.size(
                    QtCore.Qt.TextShowMnemonic, option.text)
                baseWidth = size.width() - textSize.width()
                baseHeight = size.height() - textSize.height()
                text = option.text
            else:
                baseWidth = size.width()
                baseHeight = size.height()
                text = 'XXXX' if not option.icon else ''
            buttonTextSize = self._buttonFontMetrics.size(
                QtCore.Qt.TextShowMnemonic, text)
            if not widget or widget.font() != QtWidgets.QApplication.font():
                buttonTextSize = buttonTextSize.expandedTo(
                    QtWidgets.QApplication.fontMetrics().size(
                        QtCore.Qt.TextShowMnemonic, text))
            margin = self.pixelMetric(self.PM_ButtonMargin, option, widget)
            newSize = QtCore.QSize(
                buttonTextSize.width() + baseWidth + margin * 2, 
                buttonTextSize.height() + baseHeight + margin)
            return newSize.expandedTo(
                super().sizeFromContents(contentsType, option, size, widget))
        return super().sizeFromContents(contentsType, option, size, widget)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyle(ColorButtonStyle())
# ...
```

Starting from this you could also add other properties to better control the style, such as the radius of the rounded rectangles (just replace every "4" with your variable in the border drawing, and draw the background using half of it):

```
        painter.drawRoundedRect(rect, self._radius / 2, self._radius / 2)

        if topLeftPen != bottomRightPen:
            roundRect = QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, self._radius, self._radius)
            painter.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.NoBrush)

            # the top and left borders
            tlPath = QtGui.QPainterPath()
            tlPath.arcMoveTo(roundRect.translated(
                0, rect.height() - self._radius), 225)
            tlPath.arcTo(roundRect.translated(
                   0, rect.height() - self._radius), 225, -45)
```

Comment: Wow! That's just perfect! Thanks a lot! You did all work for me! I think you right and I of course will do it by your way!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a style sheet to design it according to your liking.

Here is a self-contained example. Of course you have to adapt it to your preferred colors and dimensions. But this should already provide a starting point.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout

GREEN_BUTTON_STYLE = """
    QPushButton {
        border: 4px solid black;
        border-radius: 4px;
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: #6db442;
        font-size: 28px;
        min-height: 40px;
        min-width: 128px;
        }
    QPushButton:pressed {
        background-color: #646464;
        }
    QPushButton:flat {
        border: none;
        }
"""
RED_BUTTON_STYLE = """
    QPushButton {
        border: 4px solid black;
        border-radius: 4px;
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: #f04a50;
        font-size: 26px;
        min-height: 40px;
        min-width: 128px;
        }
    QPushButton:pressed {
        background-color: #646464;
        }
    QPushButton:flat {
        border: none;
        }
"""


class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'button styles'
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(256, 128, 384, 256)

        button1 = QPushButton('Launch')
        button1.setStyleSheet(GREEN_BUTTON_STYLE)
        button1.setFlat(True)
        button1.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

        button2 = QPushButton('Remove')
        button2.setStyleSheet(RED_BUTTON_STYLE)
        button2.setFlat(True)
        button2.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(button1, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter)
        layout.addWidget(button2, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color:#333333;")
        self.show()

    def on_click(self):
        print('clicked')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Output**

It would look like this:

[image: styled buttons]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I thought about it too. It seems that it is the only way to do it.